# how to get tow intent result in onActivityResult?

Tags: android

I am using two Intents for various actions in my activity and I also used `onActivityResult` to get a result. I want to know how to get to `Intent` result in `onActivityResult`? Can someone please provide sample code?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Intent` result is the `Intent` passed as the third parameter to `onActivityResult()`.